# I am not able to verify my domain to Google, I want to host this domain to Google Cloud platform

Tags: cloud, verification, platform

Firstly, I created a project and clicked on "Create Zone" in "Cloud DNS" and it worked fine. But later I deleted the project and made another project and it worked fine later I deleted this project too.

And again I created another project and adding on domain on "Cloud DNS" were got successful and now I deleted this project too. I do not remember exactly I created and deleted many projects. Now I made another project, But now on this project it says verify your domain which it shouldn't have said as it were not saying before. And on the other hand I am not able to even verify that domain using TXT records it fails every time I add TXT records for once I even waited for several days of waiting.

I need to verify this domain as soon as possible and host this domain on WordPress or Ghost on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071480?hl=en)

> If you get an error that says your domain verification failed, it
> could be due to timing or how you entered the verification record.
>
> 1. Wait 48 hours—Sometimes it takes up to 48 hours for the domain to be verified.
> 2. Re-enter the verification record—It's possible the
>    verification record was not created or entered correctly. You need to troubleshoot your verification method (see below).